# How to Set DIR Image in config From other domain in opencart2.3?

Tags: php, .htaccess

I want to load images for `subdomain` with `images` of other domain(`Host Download`).

Two Host , in the  `http://maindomain.com/Max88` publish of site and in the `http://OtherDomain.com` save image of site

domain host download name is example: `http://OtherDomain.com`

and Subdomain is example: `Max88`

Address of image in main domain is:

```
define('DIR_IMAGE', '/home/MainDomain/public_html/image/');
```

and This is Config of my subdomain:

```
<?php
// HTTP
define('HTTP_SERVER', 'http://MainDomain.com/Max88/');
//define('HTTP_SERVER', 'http://www.MainDomain.com/');


// HTTPS
define('HTTPS_SERVER', 'https://MainDomain.com/Max88/');
//define('HTTPS_SERVER', 'https://www.MainDomain.com/');


// DIR
define('DIR_APPLICATION', '/home/MainDomain/public_html/Max88/catalog/');
define('DIR_SYSTEM', '/home/MainDomain/public_html/Max88/system/');
//define('DIR_IMAGE', '/home/MainDomain/public_html/Max88/image/');
define('DIR_IMAGE', '/home/MainDomain/public_html/image/');
define('DIR_LANGUAGE', '/home/MainDomain/public_html/Max88/catalog/language/');
define('DIR_TEMPLATE', '/home/MainDomain/public_html/Max88/catalog/view/theme/');
define('DIR_CONFIG', '/home/MainDomain/public_html/Max88/system/config/');
define('DIR_CACHE', '/home/MainDomain/public_html/Max88/system/storage/cache/');
define('DIR_DOWNLOAD', '/home/MainDomain/public_html/Max88/system/storage/download/');
define('DIR_LOGS', '/home/MainDomain/public_html/Max88/system/storage/logs/');
define('DIR_MODIFICATION', '/home/MainDomain/public_html/Max88/system/storage/modification/');
define('DIR_UPLOAD', '/home/MainDomain/public_html/Max88/system/storage/upload/');
```

Set     `define('DIR_IMAGE', '/home/MainDomain/public_html/image/');`

But Not load Image for Subdomain.

in Home page
Address of image is:

```
   src="http://MainDomain.com/Max88/image/cache/catalog/S/x.jpg"
```

please help me.

Comment: no answer the questions?